# Removing zero from any number with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to be able to remove the first zero from any number inside given paragraph using jQuery.

Meaning if it's 01 or 010 I want that zero out please. I want it to be 1 or 10 or 22.

```html
<div class="et_pb_countdown_timer_container clearfix">
  <div class="num" data-short="num" data-full="num(s)">
    <p class="num_value">033</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
  var num=parseInt($(".num_value").text(),10);
  $(".num_value").text(num);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="et_pb_countdown_timer_container clearfix">
  <div class="num" data-short="num" data-full="num(s)">
    <p class="num_value">033</p>
  </div>
</div>
```